# Xcode linker is confusing symbols that should exist in Foundation as existing in another framework

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, compilation, linker

### Problem

After recently upgrading my Xcode and Swift installs to Xcode 15, when I compile and launch one of my applications, I get the following error:

```
dyld[84548]: Symbol not found: _OBJC_CLASS_$_NSError
  Referenced from: <DB944C1D-1AD6-3A8B-8BEC-D8454DC07A6A> /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AJRFoundationLinkTest-gypsogziwzwysmepcqeawntjqomo/Build/Products/Debug/AJRInterface.framework/Versions/A/AJRInterface
  Expected in:     <94BC2179-161F-39BD-BFB8-D55BBBD3B8DB> /Users/alex/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AJRFoundationLinkTest-gypsogziwzwysmepcqeawntjqomo/Build/Products/Debug/AJRFoundation.framework/Versions/A/AJRFoundation
```

So what's weird here is that `AJRInterface` seems to be expecting to find `NSError` in `AJRFoundation` rather than `Foundation`. This code all worked fine on the previous version of Xcode. Note that I did have some other changes, but I reverted to a clean copy with `git`, and the error still reproduced, so the only "change" here is the compiler and linker versions.

Does anyone have any idea of how to possibly diagnose this?

### Attempted Diagnostics

I'm a bit at a loss as to how to diagnose this one. I did played around with `otool` using various options trying to see if some piece of code in `AJRInterface` was somehow referencing something in `AJRFoundation` rather than `Foundation`, but I couldn't find anything obvious.

Likewise, I tried `otool` on `AJRFoundation` to see if I was somehow defining a class called `NSError`, but I also couldn't find anything.

Note that `otool` and `Swift` don't play completely nice with each, especially because `otool` doesn't de-mangle `Swift` names, which makes reading the output a little awkward.

### Hack of a Workaround

For the moment, I've managed to work around this by adding the following code to `AJRFoundation`:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated"
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-property-implementation"
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wincomplete-implementation"
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wprotocol"
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wobjc-designated-initializers"

@implementation NSError

+ (id)allocWithZone:(struct _NSZone *)zone {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.apple.Foundation"];
    if (bundle != nil) {
        struct objc_object *instance = (__bridge struct objc_object *)([super allocWithZone:zone]);
        Class class = [bundle classNamed:@"NSError"];
        if (class != Nil) {
            AJRLogWarning(@"NSError hack was triggered, swizzling isa pointer.");
            instance->isa = class;
        }
        return (__bridge NSError *)(instance);
    }
    return [super allocWithZone:zone];
}

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

@end
```

But this is obviously a horrible, horrible hack, and it can't stay in the code long term, even if it will theoretically "fix" an instance of the `AJRFoundation` `NSError` to refer to the correct one in `Foundation`.

I would submit this to Apple's bug tracker, since the cause of the issue happened due to an upgrade in the tool chain, but the frameworks that reproduce this are rather large (about 26000 lines of code). If I can find out what's causing the issue, and it is a bug rather than something I'm doing wrong, I can hopefully make a smaller test case to submit.

Comment: I can only confirm having this issue seen in our code elsewhere, more precisely in SwiftUI previews. Maybe there is a corrupt module in the cache. In all helplessness, you may deleting the DerivedData folder and hope for the best. In any case, please file a bug report.

Comment: I tried that. Both full project cleans as well as removing the entire ~/Library/Developer/Xcode folder. Same problem persisted. I'm suspicious that some Swift "glue" code for the Obj-C bridging maybe at fault, but I can't verify that. I'll also note that I've had the same issue on Catalina and now Sonoma.